# PHP and SQL(Trying to update my database using submit button)

Tags: php, html, mysql

I am trying to update my feedback in my SQL database form with help of submit button but I'm unable to do so. Please help!

```
if (isset($_POST['submitreport'])) 
            {
                $dbCon = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","Hun");
                $report = strip_tags($_POST['report']);

                $sql = "UPDATE Feedback SET report='$report' WHERE username='$username' AND date='$date' ";

                $query = mysqli_query($dbCon, $sql);


            }
```

Comment: Any error? please give some more detail.

Comment: In $username= strip_tags($_POST['report']). is it correct? report as username

Comment: The report column is not changing in the database after submitting it.

Comment: Please check with  $date condition  it matters lot if  the last condition is not matched  it will not do anything

Comment: Yes, The $date condition is correct.

Answer (score 0):

```
    <?php
    if (isset($_POST['submitreport'])) 
    {
    $dbCon = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","Hun");
    $username = 'test';
    $report = strip_tags($_POST['report']);
    $date = date('m-d-Y');

    $sql = "UPDATE Feedback SET report='".$report."' WHERE username='".$username."' AND date='".$date."'";

    $query = mysqli_query($dbCon, $sql);
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: @Kenneth: Kindly, set the value of $username variable. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
      if (isset($_POST['submitreport'])) 

    {
       $monthDayYear = date('m-d-Y');

       $dbConnnection = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","Hun");

       $dbUsername = strip_tags($_POST['report']);

       $sqlQuery = "UPDATE Feedback SET report='".$report."' WHERE username='".$username."' AND date='".$monthDayYear."'";

       $queryExecute = mysqli_query($dbConnection, $sqlQuery);


       }

    ?>
```